# Joomla 2.5 - Is it possibile to load system messages inside jdoc content?

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-template

I have the following code:

```
<div id="content">
    <?php if(count($app->getMessageQueue())) { ?>
        <jdoc:include type="message" />
    <?php } ?>
    <jdoc:include type="component" />
</div><!--#content-->
```

Everything works fine expect when there are error or system generated messages. When they are presented output looks like:

```
<div id="content">
    Some error messages
    <h1>Some page title</h1>
    <p>Some content</p>
</div><!--#content-->
```

I want to they looks like:

```
<div id="content">
    <h1>Some page title</h1>
    Some error messages
    <p>Some content</p>
</div><!--#content-->
```

So error messages should be below h1 tag and before p tag. How to achieve that without hacking core files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If am not wrong, just swap the two lines (1st as `component` and 2nd as `message`).

```
<div id="content">
    <jdoc:include type="component" />
    <?php if(count($app->getMessageQueue())) { ?>
        <jdoc:include type="message" />
    <?php } ?>
</div><!--#content-->
```

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, I have updated my post. Error message should be between h1 and p tag.